# BAD response from Idp in Auth code xchange

Tags: java

When I go to debug mode on Google Home Simulator, then copy and paste in browser  and try to link account, I am not able to link account.

Implemented outh server with authorization code, it is working for Amazon alexa, but not able to link on google Home.

What can be the issue?